# Access wrapping object's properties from nested object's getter

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to access a wrapping object's properties from a nested object's getter function?

Example:

```
class Wrapper {
  property = 'test';

  nestedObj = {
    get wrapperProperty() {
      return this.property; // Error: this.property is undefined
    }
  }
}
```

I am aware that I can do this without a getter, by using a lambda expression like so:

```
nestedObj = {
  wrapperProperty: () => this.property
}
```

And I'll do that as a last resort, but I'd really much prefer to use a getter for this, if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an immediately-invoked function expression to close over the outer `this`:

```
class Wrapper {
  property = 'test';

  nestedObj = ((that) => ({
    get wrapperProperty() {
      return that.property;
    }
  }))(this);
}
```

Comment: Clever. And not too much overhead, either. Ultimately I found a different approach that circumvents the above problem, which in turn is easier to read, but I'll keep this in mind as a neat trick.

Answer (score 0):

We can desugarize [Field declarations](http://%20https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#field-declarations) and save reference to instance:

```
class Wrapper {
  property = 'test';

  constructor() {
    var that = this;

    this.nestedObj = {
      get wrapperProperty() {
        return that.property;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The downside is that the `nestedObj` property has to be declared separately, and its type has to be kept in sync with the assignment in the constructor.